# Crash on Google Play Services update from a Google Maps API v2 MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

In my Android project, I have a MapView (API v2) which works fine on recent devices (S. Galaxy S3, Google Play Services are up to date) but if I try it on old devices (LG-C550, Google Play Services not up to date), I obtain an error message with a button to update services. The problem is that the application crashes after clicking on it.

[image] [image]

My stack traces:

```
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:648)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8960)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
02-16 06:47:51.537: E/AndroidRuntime(4078):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The runtime exception come from the Google Maps view (created by the library) which try to start a Google Play Services updater from my application context without the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Do you think if there is a way to correct this exception which is thrown by the Google Play library?

My MapActivity class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    private MapView mapView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext()) {
            {
                addView(mapView = new MapView(getApplicationContext()) {
                    {
                        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake with this Google Groups topic: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/Nb1kCQB4fJo/m7rQQD9CLIEJ

I had to give **activity context** and not **application context** to create MapView instance:

```
addView(mapView = new MapView(getApplicationContext()) {
```

replaced by:

```
addView(mapView = new MapView(MapActivity.this) {
```

If Google Team see this post, please can you precise it in your doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html?hl=fr#MapView(android.content.Context) ? I think this is very important